# How to use a dependency property in the same user control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control that defines a dependecy property to can use communicate with another user control.

This dependency propperty is in the code behind.

In this user control I have a combobox, from which I want to notify the selected item to the second user control.

The code of the first user control:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TipoComponenteSeleccionadoProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TipoComponenteSeleccionado", typeof(TiposComponentes),
            typeof(ucClasificacionesComponentesBaseView), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public bool TipoComponenteSeleccionado
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)GetValue(TipoComponenteSeleccionadoProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TipoComponenteSeleccionadoProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

I was trying something like that in the xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbTiposComponentes" Width="150"
          TipoComponenteSeleccionado="{Binding ElementName=cmbTiposComponentes, Path=SelectedItem}">
```

The idea is when I select the item in the combobox, update the dependency property, so the second user control can bind it and be notified.

But I get an errror because the dependency property can't be used in the combobox.

So I was wondering if there is some way to use the dependency property in the combobox.

I have tried to define a static resource in the xaml of the first user control, something like that:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MyMainUserControl.DependencyProperty Key.../>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

But the itellisense shows me all the views that I have except this, so I don't have access to the depedency property of the view.

So is it possible to use the dependency property in the view in which it is defined?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind SelectedItem to TipoComponenteSeleccionado:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbTiposComponentes" Width="150"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=TipoComponenteSeleccionado, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:TiposComponentes}}}">
```

Comment: As a note, the Binding is TwoWay by default. And you would usually just write `{Binding TipoComponenteSeleccionado, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}`.